# Date & time comparison operators >= not showing dates that are equal

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to show events that occur either today or on a later date where today is specifically the problem.

```
public function getInspirationsMeetingIds()
{
    $ids = [];
    if (($inspirationMeetings = $this->getCustomField('meetings'))) {

        foreach ($inspirationMeetings as $meeting) {

            $row = new Inspiration($meeting['meeting']);

            $dateFrom = $row->getCustomField('date');

            if (strtotime($dateFrom) >= time()) {
                $ids[] = $row->getId();
            }

        }
    }
     return $ids;
}
```

For some reason this will only show events that are greater than time() and not the events that are today, but then when i try this:

```
if (strtotime($dateFrom) <= time()) {
            $ids[] = $row->getId();
}
```

Today's and older events are shown.

Comment: time is in seconds. the chances of you hitting the exact second are very slim

Comment: Probably because the time() shows current time and the date has a timestamp prior to time().

Comment: What format is `$dateFrom` ?

Comment: I don't think the format matters since strtotime will always add a time of the day if it's missing. https://3v4l.org/cYKO4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a timestamp to your datefrom.

Strtotime will add noon if time is omitted.
See this example https://3v4l.org/cYKO4

```
if (strtotime($dateFrom ) >= strtotime(date("Y-m-d 00:00"))) {
```

Will make it show all of datefrom

Edit added the 00:00 at the wrong side

Comment: Now you are using `date()` and not `time()`? I told you time wouldn't work.

Comment: Im sure. But I forgot strtotime

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateTime class http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

`time()` gives seconds since Jan 1st 1970. The chance that you hit the exact second is very small, so it will hardly ever match.

Instead, create a date with the time.

```
$date = new DateTime($dateFrom); // or DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dateFrom);
$today = new DateTime();

if ($date >= $today) {
   // should work
}
```

Comment: That is not the problem. Both time and strtotime shows the time in seconds. And since it's a `>=` comparison it's not a matter of "one second"

Comment: He's trying to match today, but he is comparing with a specific second of today. that is his problem. Anything greater than is fine, but he is having problems with the = part.

Comment: I'm afraid you are incorrect. Look. I created a time for today (9AM) and compare it with time(). Of course it is not >=, it is less, and therefore won't match https://3v4l.org/82N2I